# Error Running and building old visual basic website localhost.ne

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Could not create type 'Telerik.WebControls.SpellCheckHandler'.

Comment: When there are several Telerik.Web.UI assemblies in the GAC you need to fully qualify your assembly reference, otherwise an ambiguous reference might occur.

Comment: Try adding the following line in the 
<assemblies> section in web.config
<add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2009.2.701.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121FAE78165BA3D4"/>

Comment: Version should match with the Telerik Assembly that you have added in your project

Comment: the project its using an old version of telerik RadEditor.net2 dll How do I know the version on Version= ?

Comment: Right click on Telerik.Web.UI.dll assembly in visual studio, click properties and check version

Comment: I dont have a Telerik.Web.UI.dll assembly on the solution just one name RadEditor.Net2.dll

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this mechanism you need to setup the `SpellCheck HttpHandler` in one of the following ways:
Register the `HttpHandler` in the application’s `web.config` file
Open the application’s `web.config` file, located at the root folder of your application.
In the `<system.web>` section, locate the `<httpHandlers>` subsection. If it is missing, create it:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers></httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Inside the `<httpHandlers>` section add the following declaration:

```
<add verb="POST" type="Telerik.WebControls.SpellCheckHandler, RadSpell.Net2" path="Telerik.RadSpellCheckHandler.ashx"/>
```

Create a new text file, named `Telerik.RadSpellCheckHandler.ashx`, inside the `~/RadControls/Spell` folder, where the tilde (~) represents the application’s root folder. Put the following text in that file:

```
<%@ WebHandler language="c#" Class="Telerik.WebControls.SpellCheckHandler" %>
```

GAC configuration:
If the `RadSpell.Net2.dll` is placed in the GAC (Clobal Assemly Cache), here is the configuration for the two methods of usage above:
Declare the handler in the web.config file as shown below:

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="POST" type="Telerik.WebControls.SpellCheckHandler, RadSpell.Net2, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b5dad7bf2bf594c2" path="Telerik.RadSpellCheckHandler.ashx"/>
   </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Edit the Telerik.RadSpellCheckHandler.ashx as follows:

```
<%@ WebHandler language="c#" Class="Telerik.WebControls.SpellCheckHandler, RadSpell.Net2, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b5dad7bf2bf594c2" %>
```